# Fabric network org structure for peers and orderers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I would like to know what is the best practice or preferred method to design a fabric network in 2.x versions? Shall we have orderers in the same organization as peers or should we need to have a separate org for orderers? Or should we have two different orgs for peers and orderers for each participating orgs? Can anyone shed some light and point me to resources?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the real-world problem you are trying to solve.

The only requirement for production networks is that you have an ordering service with Raft Consensus.
At least 3 ordering nodes, because if it was only 1 node, it can go down and the network would not be able to cut new blocks, and if it is an even number of nodes (i.e. 2 nodes or 4 nodes) Raft would have a hard time electing a leader. In production, 5 ordering nodes are recommended.

Now that you have decided on the number of ordering nodes for the ordering service, you have to decide which organizations should contribute an ordering node to the service. This is where you specific use-case comes at play. For example, a regulatory body contributes 2 ordering nodes, and the other 3 ordering nodes are owned by separate businesses that the regulatory body oversees.

As for the peer nodes, any organization can have as many as required, even if they have ordering nodes. For example, a regulatory body may have 1 peer node and 2 ordering nodes on the same channel.

To sum it up, organizations can have as many peers as needed. For the ordering service, you have to select the organizations that will contribute ordering nodes to the ordering service. This selection process is dependent on your specific use-case.